# Phantom.js does not play well with redirects

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, phantomjs

A bit of preamble:

I am responsible for a corporate site (semi-internal) that has a single URL (and IP address) and as soon as you visit it, it starts redirecting you to one of a number of sub-pages (redirects happen approximately every 1 minute). This is used mainly for testing and monitoring purposes.

Now, I wanted to run some tests on that site, and monitor the redirect process. For this purpose I wrote a simple Phantom.js script, using Node.js and the appropriate wrapper:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var URL = 'http://www.lololololololol.com'

var userAgentString = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible, MSIE 11, Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0;  rv:11.0) like Gecko';

phantom.create(function (ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
        page.set('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1080 });
        page.set('settings.javascriptEnabled', true);
        page.set('settings.loadImages', true);
        page.set('settings.localToRemoteUrlAccess', true);
        page.set('settings.userAgent', userAgentString);
        page.set('settings.webSecurityEnabled', false);
        page.set('settings.resourceTimeout', 5000);     

        page.open(URL, function (status) {
            if (status == 'success') {
                page.evaluate(function (result) {
                    return document.title;
                }, function (result) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log('Status: ' + status);
                        ph.exit();
                    }, 1000 * 3600);
                }); 
            } else if (status == 'fail') {
                console.log('Status: ' + status);
                ph.exit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

What this does is open the website and stay 'inside' for 1 hour, then exit everything. This appears to work because if I add a 'setInterval()' to execute 'page.render(hahaha.png)' every 10 seconds, I get screenshots that show the different pages.

Now, the problem is this. I looked accidentally at the Google Analytics records for the site (why this thing is being monitored in the first place, i do not know) and it says 'Bounce Rate: 100%'. If I am correct, this means that the 'visitors' only viewed a single page, the one they landed on. But is this not contrary to the redirects happening correctly?

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of PhantomJS are you using? You might try with 1.9.8, because if analytics is served over https, it might not give the correct data pre-1.9.8. Or try setting the `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1`: `phantom.create("--ssl-protocol=tlsv1", function (ph) {`

Comment: @ArtjomB. It is indeed version 1.9.8-1. Also, Analytics logs the number of visits to the page correctly. The Bounce rate is what troubles me. It looks like the redirects happen inside phantom.js (because the screenshots say so) but Analytics ignores them.

Comment: @ArtjomB. No. I mean the version of Phantom.js installed with the package manager (pacman).